# Execute thread with same rights as main program?

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi

I have a form in my application that executes an LDAP query. But, since each result-item requires some processing I decided to process each item in a separate thread. Alas, I quickly realized that the processing (which calls some methods in a COM object) refuse to work - because (or "perhaps" is a better word) the thread does not spawn under the same user account.
The COM part is working fine, but the code that would return the correct information if executed as part of the program - does not return the correct information when executed in a thread. When I googled this I found information pointing to security descriptors and tokens. Which I must admit I have very little experience with.

Can anyone please show me how you make a TThread class execute as the user who started and is operating my main program?

We use Delphi XE3. The program executes on Windows 7 via Citrix/AD.

Thank you so much for your help

Updated: ** This turned out to be a COM issue rather than a threading issue.
The username param for the COM was expected to be UTF8. The thread works fine now.

Thanks to everyone for sharing their knowledge!

Comment: How do you make this diagnosis?

Comment: By the fact that the resulting AD object displays only information that is visible to guest accounts. The moment I hit a user that that is invisible to a guestaccount - the data is blank.

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to access?

Comment: The AD object for that user, to extract the account GUID from the SID. Also I check if the account is locked/disabled and i fetch the user description. It is very odd. It works fine if i execute it in the main thread, but it refuses to work under a thread. And yes, coInitialize is setup for the thread and the COM helper responds without errors.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access an object marshaled to another thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong.  A thread DOES run in the same user account and access rights as its parent process.  It takes extra code (impersonation, etc) to change that behavior.  So something else is going on.  You need to keep investigating.  If you want help, you need to show your actual code.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question to better reflect the problem.

Comment: You were right. This was not a threading issue, but rather a COM issue. It works now. Thank you!